# Entity Framework - How can I check whether an object is under another object's Hierarchy?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an table called Contents. There's one to many relationship on Contents, so each content can have a parent and children. I'm using EF Code First, so I have an entity `Content` which has `Id`, `ParentId`, `Parent` and `Children` properties.

Now, I'm building an ajax based tree of Contents. I have a simple action that returns a JSON of one level of Contents, based on `parentId`:

```
public JsonResult GetContents(int? parentId = null)
{
    return Json(db.Contents
        .Where(p => p.ParentId == parentId)
        .Select(p => new
        {
            id = p.Id,
            name = p.Name
        });
}
```

The next thing I want to do is to automatically select some value. The problem is that the value can be deep inside the hierarchy of the tree, so for each content I'll need to know whether or not the selected value is a child or grandchild and so forth, of it.

```
public JsonResult GetContents(int? parentId = null, int selectedValue)
{
    return Json(db.Contents
        .Where(p => p.ParentId == parentId)
        .Select(p => new
        {
            id = p.Id,
            name = p.Name
            isSelectedValueUnderThisHierarchy: // How can I efficiently implement this? 
        });
}
```

It's easy to implement with a lot of queries, but I'm trying to make things as efficient as possible, and EF doesn't provide any Recursive methods as far as I know, so I really have no clue where to start.

Comment: I can't get any idea how to do that without recurring function, however, I would like to point that you shouldn't compare p.ParentId to null (that's what you're doing in by default parameter)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that it is a zero or one to many relationship, not just a one to many relationship, so if an item doesn't have a parent, ParentId = null.

Comment: http://bit.ly/16FQkC That's why you shouldn't compare to null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first build a list of all the ParentIds from the selected value.  Depending on the size of your Contents table, you could first load the data, then loop through without making extra queries to the database.

```
db.Contents.Load();
var selectedItem = db.Contents.Find(selectedValue);

var parents = new List<int>();
while (selectedItem.ParentId != null)
{
    parents.Add(selectedItem.ParentId.Value);
    selectedItem = selectedItem.Parent;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use CTE (Common Table Expression).

```
var parents = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>("sql statement");
```

Once you have a list of parents, you can use `Contains`.

```
return Json(db.Contents
    .Where(p => p.ParentId == parentId)
    .Select(p => new
    {
        id = p.Id,
        name = p.Name
        isSelectedValueUnderThisHierarchy = p.ParentId.HasValue && parents.Contains(p.ParentId.Value)
    });
```

UPDATE: CTE Example

You'd probably want to use a stored procedure, but this code should work.

```
var sql = @"with CTE as
    (
        select ParentId
        from Contents
        where Id = {0}
        union all
        select Contents.ParentId
        from Contents
            inner join CTE on Contents.Id = CTE.ParentId    
    )

    select *
    from CTE
    where ParentId is not null";
var parents = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(string.Format(sql, selectedItem)).ToList();
```

Comment: The table is huge, so I can't just load all of it

Comment: You can use the CTE then, it will bring back only the Ids from the database in a single query.  I'll update my answer with an example.